# Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 67500]

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

**I am having an issue in predicting from cnn model**

[model structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnAU2.png)

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

import numpy as np

img = image.load_img("test/apple/apple.jpg", target_size=(150,150))

x=image.img_to_array(img) / 255

x = x.reshape(1,-1)

model.predict(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are flattening image, but your model `takes batch-wise image data`.
**Add a dimension** using [np.expand_dims](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) to the resized image and pass to model for prediction.

Try in this way.

```
img = image.load_img("test/apple/apple.jpg", target_size=(150,150))
x=image.img_to_array(img) / 255
resized_img_np = np.expand_dims(x,axis=0)
prediction = model.predict(resized_img_np)
```

Comment: array([[0.01690916]], dtype=float32)

Comment: what does it mean ---input image is from first class??

Comment: probability for first class is 0.0169 and second class is 1-0.0169